# Difference between Laravel testing method assertRedirect($uri) and assertLocation($uri)?

Tags: laravel, testing

I was reading Laravel document [HTTP tests](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-cookie-missing) and a question occurred.
I can't tell the difference between `assertLocation($uri)` and `assertRedirect($uri)`, since both are for redirecting to specific `uri`.

Anyone could help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) the Location header can be provided by a 201 response in addition to a redirect response (indicating the location the newly created resource is at) so `assertLocation` will probably pass in that case as well

Comment: @apokryfos Hey apok, thanks for your comment. I read the MDN as well. I found that both `assertLocation` and `assertRedirect` accept `$uri` parameter, which could mean that they only care about the $uri rather than status code. As stated in MDN, even though the status code is 201, the `Location` header would still point to a `uri`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes but only 3xx responses are considered to be redirect responses while a 201 is not a redirect so `assertLocation` will pass if the response is 201 with a specified location while `assertRedirect` will not pass for 201 responses (or that *should* be the behaviour)

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks Apok, I will give it a try and let you know if it behaves as what we expects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look functionality of both
`assertLocation($uri)` would assert that the current location header matches the given URI.
But `assertRedirect($uri)` would assert whether the response is redirecting to a given URI.

> I agree with example given by @apokryfos,
> `only 3xx responses are considered to be redirect responses while a 201 is not a redirect so assertLocation will pass if the response is 201 with a specified location while assertRedirect will not pass for 201 responses.`

---

If we look code wise, 
The `assertRedirect()` function also calls `assertLocation()` internally but it also checks using `PHPUnit::assertTrue()` that the response is redirected, if not then it will send a message

`'Response status code [201] is not a redirect status code.'`, where 201 specifies the status code of response.

Checkout the `assertRedirect()` from [github repo of framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php#L198)

Comment: Thanks bhucho! I've read the source code, and so we could conclude that `assertRedirect($uri)` not only checks the $uri, also the status code (it should be a redirect status code), while `assertLocation($uri)` only checks the `uri`